# Ways to seat 6 couples in a circle with 14 chairs.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there is a round table with $14$ chairs. How many ways can I seat $6$ couples around the table if I require partners of each couple to seat together?

My answer is $$\Big(\frac{13!}{8!}\Big)\cdot(2^6)$$.

I treat each couple as $1$ object. So there are $6$ objects and $8$ "ghosts". Then for each couple, they can be seated in $2$ ways. Is this correct?

Comment: Your wording suggests that the couples sit together on the same chair. Normally, people sit in separate chairs, so if there are six couples seated at a table with 14 chairs, they'll take up 12 of the chairs, leaving room for only two ghosts, not eight.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

1. take any of the 14 chairs to be empty
2. there are 7 positions allowed for the second empty chair (0,2,4,..,12 positions between them)
3. for symmetry, divide by 2, so we have 49 configurations. Your answer does not have factor 49, so I think it is incorrect.
4. permute the pairs (6!)
5. order within the pairs (2^6)
6. multiply.

Answer (score 1):

Let the couples be $U$, $V$, $W$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$.  Let $E$ refer to an empty seat.  Let the chairs be numbered $1$–$14$.  Seat couple $U$ in chairs $1$ and $2$.  To fill chairs $3$–$14$, arrange the letters of the word $VWXYZEE$, which can be done in $\frac{7!}{2!}$ ways, and place the couples and empty seats accordingly.  Now decide which member of each couple sits to the right and which to the left.  This can be done in $2^6$ ways.

If the circularity of the table is meant to imply that a cyclic permutation of the occupants of the chairs gives an equivalent arrangement, than we're done.  (Requiring that couple $U$ occupy chairs $1$ and $2$ has given us a unique representative of each equivalence class.)  Otherwise there is an additional factor of $14$ to account for all possible positions of couple $U$.

Note that the first of these answers agrees with that of fawningflagellum, the second with that of Pieter21.

Answer (score 0):

Cut down on the ghosts!
The answer is 7!2^5. Think about it!

Comment: the empty seats do not need to be paired.

Comment: @Pieter21 It depends if you consider the table fixed.

Comment: I think there can be any number of pairs between the two empty seats. And indeed, for my answer, I assume the table fixed.